# Connecting points from different groups in a categorical X axis with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, categorical-data

I am trying to visulaize the change in Abundance of A, B and C between three Methods. A, B and C are also divided in two groups ("X" and "Y"). I am trying to plot these with ggplot and connect the observations from method to method, but I have not been able to. This is what I've done:

```
factor_1 <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times =6))
Abundance <- c(sample(x = 1:100, replace = T, size = 18))
factor_2 <- c(rep(c("X", "Y"), each = 3, times = 3))
factor_3 <- c(rep(c("Method 1", "Method 2", "Method 3"), each = 6))
datframe <- tibble(factor_1, factor_2, Abundance, factor_3)
```

[The first plot only connects the dots vertically in each Method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzYdY.jpg)

```
datframe %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor_3, y = Abundance, color = factor_2))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

When trying to Group by either [factor_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPbVY.jpg) or [factor_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvcXD.jpg), it seems to connect everything in a single line

```
datframe %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor_3, y = Abundance, color = factor_2))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(group = c(factor_2))

datframe %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor_3, y = Abundance, color = factor_2))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(group = c(factor_1))
```

[Even if I plot only one row, R complains, saying "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?" and does not connect the dots.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEIDr.jpg)

```
datframe %>%
  filter(factor_1 == "A", factor_2 == "X") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor_3, y = Abundance, color = factor_2))+
           geom_point() +
           geom_line()
```

I know that it can be done when the X axis is a continuous variable, but I have failed to see it with a categorical variable.

[This is more or less what I want. It does not need even to be colored coded, since I could make two plots, one for "X" and another for "Y".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxnF7.jpg)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi Ignacio, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you clarify, perhaps with a mock up graph made with paint, preview or GIMP of what you would like the output to look like?

Comment: Hello Ian, thank you. I have made an edit and now there is a link to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is with `interaction`:

```
library(ggplot2)
datframe %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor_3, y = Abundance, color = factor_2, group = interaction(factor_1,factor_2)))+
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

You might also consider including a second visual aesthetic to differentiate `factor_1`.

```
datframe %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor_3, y = Abundance, color = factor_2, linetype = factor_1, group = interaction(factor_1,factor_2)))+
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
datframe <- tibble(factor_1 = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times =6),
                   Abundance = sample(x = 1:100, replace = T, size = 18),
                   factor_2 = rep(c("X", "Y"), each = 3, times = 3),
                   factor_3 = rep(c("Method 1", "Method 2", "Method 3"), each = 6))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ian! This was exactly what I was trying to do. Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 3):

is this what you are looking for??

```
datframe %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor_1, y = Abundance, color = factor_2, group = factor_2))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~factor_3)
```

[image]

Comment: No, sorry. I would like to keep the Methods as the X axis and all in one plot. "A + X" values in each method, for example, should be conected in one line

Comment: I have now included an image of what I would like to plot.